# how do I overcome substr and clob limitation?

Tags: oracle, plsql, substr, clob

I have an XML which is stored in a clob. I need to run various substr and instr functions in order to display specific data from the XML.

My current code handles it using a varchar2 (32000) variable as below:

```
select xml_data into xmlclob
                 from test.test_data_v6 
                 where test_id =r1.test_id;

                 start_position := dbms_lob.instr(xmlclob,'<DataSheet>',1,1)+11;
                 end_position := dbms_lob.instr(xmlclob,'</DataSheet>',start_position,1);                         
                 l_str := (dbms_lob.substr(xmlclob, end_position - start_position, start_position));                   
                 l_str := substr(l_str, instr(l_str, '<SummaryParameters>'),instr(l_str, '</SummaryParameters>')-instr(l_str, '<SummaryParameters>')+20);
```

l_str is a varchar2.

This does not display the substrings in case the length is larger than 32000 which i assume is the limitation of varchar. So i changed the l_str to clob variable and did the below:

```
select xml_data into xmlclob
                 from test.test_data_v6_temp 
                 where test_id =r1.test_id;

                 start_position := dbms_lob.instr(xmlclob,'<DataSheet>',1,1)+11;
                 end_position := dbms_lob.instr(xmlclob,'</DataSheet>',start_position,1);                         
                 l_str := dbms_lob.substr(xmlclob, end_position - start_position, start_position);
                 l_str1 := substr(l_str, instr(l_str, '<SummaryParameters>'), instr(l_str, '</SummaryParameters>')-instr(l_str, '<SummaryParameters>')+20);
```

This gives null in case of xmls which have end_position-start_position more than 32000 as well.

I wrote an anonymous block to test out the limit of the substring as below:

```
declare
error_reason varchar2(32000);
start_position number;
end_position number;
str_length number;
str_length2 number;
l_clob2 clob;
l_str varchar2(32000);
e_clob clob;
temp_clob clob;
begin
           select xml_data into l_clob2 from test.test_data_v6_temp where test_id=(hard coded the test id);

           start_position := dbms_lob.instr(l_clob2,'<DataSheet>',1,1)+11;
           dbms_output.put_line('startposition='||start_position);
           end_position := dbms_lob.instr(l_clob2,'</DataSheet>',start_position,1);
           dbms_output.put_line('end position='||end_position);
           str_length := end_position-start_position;
           str_length2 := 30000;
           dbms_output.put_line('str_length='||str_length);
           dbms_output.put_line('str_length2='||str_length2);
           dbms_output.put_line('str_length='||str_length);

                        temp_clob := dbms_lob.substr(l_clob2, str_length2, start_position);
                   --dbms_output.put_line('temp_clob1='||temp_clob);
                  --temp_clob := substr(temp_clob, instr(temp_clob, '<SummaryParameters>'), instr(temp_clob, '</SummaryParameters>')-instr(temp_clob, '<SummaryParameters>')+20);
                  insert into test.temp values(temp_clob);
                 commit;

end;

--select * from test.temp
```

i commented out the 2nd substring just to see if my table gets populated with data if i change the str_length to anything below 32000 and it does get populated.

here's my output

```
startposition=202134
end position=237746
str_length=35612
str_length2=30000
```

how do i overcome this limit of substr and clob to get proper data?

Editing after receiving answers:
I tried out the Copy solution but the problem i have is the SummaryParameters is inside the DataSheet tag in the XML. Putting it in the loop the 2nd iteration for SummaryParametes cannot find the end tag for the same. Also in the XML extract function i used the getStringVal() method and that also returns a varchar which again has the size issue. I'm not sure how do i use the copy function to get to the Summary Parameters inside DataSheet tag (i cannot directly look for the SummaryParameters  tag since there are others outside the DataSheet Tag as well. here's my code:

```
declare
start_position number;
end_position number;
str_length number;
str_length2 number;
sp2 number;
ep2 number;
str_len number;
 str_len2 number;
 l_clob2 clob;
temp_clob clob;
temp_clob2 clob;
 begin
               select xml_data into l_clob2 from test.test_data_v6_temp where test_id=211230309;

             start_position := dbms_lob.instr(l_clob2,'<DataSheet>',1,1)+11;
            dbms_output.put_line('startposition='||start_position);
           end_position := dbms_lob.instr(l_clob2,'</DataSheet>',start_position,1);
               dbms_output.put_line('end position='||end_position);
               str_length := end_position-start_position;

            dbms_output.put_line('Original clob size: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(l_clob2));
            dbms_lob.createtemporary(temp_clob, false);
            while str_length > 0 
            loop
            str_length2 := least(str_length, 32768);
            str_length := str_length - str_length2;
            dbms_lob.copy(temp_clob, l_clob2, str_length2,dbms_lob.getlength(temp_clob) + 1, start_position);
            start_position := start_position + str_length;
              end loop;
             dbms_output.put_line('Copied clob 1 size: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(temp_clob));
             sp2 := dbms_lob.instr(temp_clob,'<SummaryParameters>')+20;
                dbms_output.put_line('sp2 = '|| sp2);
              ep2 := instr(temp_clob, '</SummaryParameters>');
                dbms_output.put_line('ep2 = '|| ep2);

              str_len :=ep2 - sp2;
              dbms_lob.createtemporary(temp_clob2, false);
             while str_len > 0 
              loop
                str_len2 := least(str_len, 32768);
                str_len := str_len - str_len2;
                dbms_lob.copy(temp_clob2, temp_clob, str_len2,dbms_lob.getlength(temp_clob2) + 1, sp2);
                sp2 := sp2 + str_len;
              end loop; 


            dbms_output.put_line('Copied 2 clob size: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(temp_clob2));

 insert into test.temp values(temp_clob2);
                  commit;
end;
```

Here's My output:

```
startposition=202134
end position=237746
Original clob size: 1723831
Copied clob 1 size: 35612
sp2 = 703
ep2 = 0
Copied 2 clob size: 0
```

Comment: `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` always returns a `VARCHAR2`; trying to assign that to a new LBO doesn't avoid the 32k limit at all. Can you use [`COPY`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66662) instead - you should still be able to get the offsets with `INSTR`, but keep it to LOB operations only?

Comment: If you have a XML (even as clob) you probably should process it as a XML not as a string.

Comment: @Alex Poole :how do i use copy here? I'm not sure. I'm not very familiar with dbms_lob functions.

Comment: Does it change when you declare `l_str CLOB;` instead of VARCHAR2(32000)?

Comment: @Wernfried: No it does not change. thats my issue. We hadn't encountered any XML's so far which were this big, so the Varchar2 was working fine. Now i want the code to handle any length of characters. and CLOB does not help :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using the `COPY` procedure to avoid switching to `VARCHAR2`:

```
   dbms_output.put_line('Original clob size: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(l_clob2));
   dbms_lob.createtemporary(temp_clob, false);
   while str_length > 0 loop
     str_length2 := least(str_length, 32768);
     str_length := str_length - str_length2;
     dbms_lob.copy(temp_clob, l_clob2, str_length2,
       dbms_lob.getlength(temp_clob) + 1, start_position);
     start_position := start_position + str_length2;
   end loop;
   dbms_output.put_line('Copied clob size: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(temp_clob));
```

With an 'XML' value I populated, that gives me output:

```
startposition=17
end position=40456
str_length=40439
str_length2=30000
str_length=40439
Original clob size: 40473
Copied clob size: 40439
```

So `temp_clob` contains a 40k+ 'substring' of the original CLOB.

---

@user272735 is right though, if the column is holding XML data then it should be handled as such (and preferably stored that way too, as an XMLType rather than a CLOB, which it seems to be now).

You can avoid this work by extracting the relevant data from the XML with something like:

```
select xmlquery('*/DataSheet/SummaryParameters/*'
  passing xmltype(xml_data) returning content))
from ...
```

Or in older versions (deprecated in 11gR2):

```
select extract(xmltype(xml_data), '*/DataSheet/SummaryParameters/*')
from ...
```

Either of which would give you the section inside the `<SummaryParameters>...</SummaryParameters>`. It isn't clear from your question whether `DataSheet` is the top element, or whether `SummaryParameters` is directly inside that element, so you might need to experiment with where to put the wildcards. [More about XMLQuery in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm).

---

Using two copy statements works to get the inner `SummaryParameters` section:

```
declare
  start_position number;
  end_position number;
  str_length number;
  str_length2 number;
  l_clob2 clob;
  temp_clob clob;
  temp_clob2 clob;
begin
  select xml_data into l_clob2 from t42 where id = 1;

  start_position := dbms_lob.instr(l_clob2,'<DataSheet>',1,1)+11;
  dbms_output.put_line('startposition='||start_position);
  end_position := dbms_lob.instr(l_clob2,'</DataSheet>',start_position,1);
  dbms_output.put_line('end position='||end_position);
  str_length := end_position-start_position;

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(temp_clob, false);
  while str_length > 0 loop
    str_length2 := least(str_length, 32768);
    str_length := str_length - str_length2;
    dbms_lob.copy(temp_clob, l_clob2, str_length2,
      dbms_lob.getlength(temp_clob) + 1, start_position);
    start_position := start_position + str_length2;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('temp_clob length: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(temp_clob));

  start_position := dbms_lob.instr(temp_clob,'<SummaryParameters>',1,1)+19;
  dbms_output.put_line('startposition='||start_position);
  end_position := dbms_lob.instr(temp_clob,'</SummaryParameters>',start_position,1);
  dbms_output.put_line('end position='||end_position);
  str_length := end_position-start_position;

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(temp_clob2, false);
  while str_length > 0 loop
    str_length2 := least(str_length, 32768);
    str_length := str_length - str_length2;
    dbms_lob.copy(temp_clob2, temp_clob, str_length2,
      dbms_lob.getlength(temp_clob2) + 1, start_position);
    start_position := start_position + str_length2;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('temp_clob2 length: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(temp_clob2));

  insert into t42 values (2, temp_clob2);
end;
/
```

Gives (with my made-up data):

```
startposition=17
end position=40456
temp_clob length: 40439
startposition=220
end position=420
temp_clob2 length: 200
```

Comment: I tried out your Copy solution but the problem i have is the Summary parameters is inside the Data Sheet tag in the XML. Putting it in the loop the 2nd iteration for SummaryParameters cannot find the end tag for the same. Also the XML extract function i used the getStringVal() method and that also returns a varchar whiich again has the size issue. I'm not sure how do i use the copy function to get to the Summary Parameters inside data sheet (i cannot directly look for the SummaryParameters tag since there are others outside the DataSheet Tag as well. (edited the question with my new code)

Comment: @amsko - aside from your code having `+20` instead of `+19`, your version works for me too. Is it really well-formed XML - specifically does it have the `</SummaryParameters>` closing tag in the right place, and with that exact capitalisation? Since your second `end_position` gets zero, it looks like it doesn't. (Which means the XML functions wouldn't like it either).

Comment: Yes I checked the XML. It does contain the </SummaryParameters> tag. i think the first iteration of the loop only gives 32768 characters and thats why the end tag is not included in it till the next iteration. I'm not sure how to work around that problem.

Comment: When it builds `temp_clob` the first iteration gets 32k, the second adds the rest, so I don't see why that would be a problem - it doesn't look for the `</SummaryParameters>` end tag until that loop is complete. (Unless I'm out by a character somewhere and it happens to fall in the middle of t tag; but it matches `str_length`). Your `temp_clob` is 35612 chars; the issue is why `ep2` is zero, so why it thinks that doesn't contain `</SummaryParameters>`... with my values, where the tags are nested, this works. Strange.

Comment: @amsko - oh, no, you're right; with the inner tag later in the DataSheet it broke. My `start_position` adjustment was wrong; everything after 32k in `temp_clob` would have been empty. I've changed `start_position := start_position + str_length;` to `start_position := start_position + str_length2;`. If you do the same (in both copy loops) it ought to work now. Sorry.

Comment: Yes!! this works @Alex Poole, but now i have one more issue. The next code does the foll: `code`         
                    dbms_lob.writeappend ( e_clob, dbms_lob.getlength(temp_clob2), temp_clob2 );   
                     select substr(replace(replace(xmltype(e_clob).extract('//RangeSpecification[Pass="false"]/Name').getStringVal(),'</Name>',','), '<Name>', ''),1,1000)
               into error_reason
               from dual;   `code` eclob is another temp clob. I'm guessing the substr problem affects this too since error_reason is now empty. :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try XML Functions, e.g. [UPDATEXML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb04cre.htm#CHDBIJCB) to modify the XML, instead of using pure string functions on CLOB.

Maybe like this:

```
DECLARE
   xmlval XMLType;
BEGIN

SELECT xml_data INTO xmlval 
FROM TEST.test_data_v6_temp 
WHERE test_id =r1.test_id;

xmlval := UPDATEXML(xmlval, '/DataSheet', 'SummaryParameters');

END;
```

You just have to find the proper X-Path expression and replacement.

Other XML functions are

```
DELETEXML 
INSERTCHILDXML  
INSERTCHILDXMLAFTER
INSERTCHILDXMLBEFORE
INSERTXMLAFTER 
INSERTXMLBEFORE 
XMLELEMENT
XMLCONCAT
```

Maybe one of them helps you.